# New Standard user autoloads on boot

Tags: 13.10, login, users

I've been using Ubuntu since about v8.09, now running 13.10, but only ever as a single user - and I'm a *user*, not a programmer or guru. Now I have a new partner who would like to learn to use a computer, so I created a new user profile for her, (through the Unity Systems Settings/User Accounts control) complete with password, as a standard user. Password is set, Auto-login is disabled, yet whenever I boot up the machine, she is logged in as the active user and I have to log her out before I log in (well, I don't *have* to but...). Thing is, it's not supposed to auto-login anyone, so how do I set things up so it doesn't? So it behaves the way it's supposed to?

Comment: If you could update your question with the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and with the relevant sections of `/var/log/auth.log` that would be helpful.

Comment: /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf as follows (user ID replaced with'username':
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
autologin-user=username

/var/log/auth.log is an empty file, size 0 bytes
Even to the unskilled like me, it's fairly obvious that Ubuntu's control panel has marked the new user for auto-login, which it should not do. Even if we find a workaround, I think this is a bug which needs flagging up to the developers.

Comment: That is possible that it is a bug, please consider filing a bugreport. But to solve the issue just remove that line as I presented it in my answer. (it is not a workaround, but correcting the bug.) How can the `auth.log` be empty I don't know, maybe you looked at it right after a logrotate, so you should be looking at `auth.log.1`. But that file is likely unimportant now, because we found the guilty line in `lightdm.conf`.

Comment: Or as I now see there are some bugreports saying that `auth.log` is empty on some systems. So you might having not 1 but 2 bugs. :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but if your account is passworded and your partner's not then it might just load the unpassworded account. Try setting a test password on your partner's account and see what it will do, even for curiosity sake.

Comment: *Both* accounts are password protected from setup; however in trying to figure out what's happening, the password on the new account seems to make no difference; I've tried it both with an without and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your `lightdm.conf` file contains the line:

```
autologin-user=username
```

which will automatically login the user named `username`. So just remove that line from the `lightdm.conf` file.